# Jquery event.target.id gets more than one id

Tags: html, jquery

I'm developing a table that fills its empty spaces with the selected options of a `<select>`.
So i decided to use Jquery to get the id of the clicked (empty) target and put the text value of the option inside of it.

I've created the variable:

`var id = (event.target.id);`

and through a test div I can see that it gets different id's everytime i click on a different place.

```
$( "#log" ).html( "You clicked " + testo + id);
```

So i'm using this function through a confirmation button to put the text inside the selected div.

```
if (testo === ' ') {
  $("#modale").modal('show');
  $("#confirm-button").click(function() {
    var selected = $("select#selezione option:selected").text();
    $("#" + id).html(selected);
    $("#modale").modal('hide');
  });
}
```

It Works fine untill i choose another empty div... it fills the new empty div with the selected option but replaces even the first one.

Snippet:

```
$(".richiamo").click(function(event) {
      var testo = $(event.target).text();
      var id = (event.target.id);
      $("#log").html("You clicked: " + testo + id);

      if (testo === ' ') {
        $("#modale").modal('show');
        $("#confirm-button").click(function() {
          var selected = $("select#selezione option:selected").text();
          $("#" + id).html(selected);
          $("#modale").modal('hide');
        });
      }
```

Comment: Please share your HTML also.

Comment: Adding a click handler inside another click handler is usually wrong. The second click handler will run multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the second click handler inside the first one. Every time you click on `.richiamo` it adds another click handler on `#confirm-button`, and each of them remembers the `id` of the `.richiamo` button that added it in its closure.

Instead of nesting the click handlers, bind the handler once and use a global variable to hold the id.

```
var richiamo_id;

$(".richiamo").click(function(event) {
  var testo = $(event.target).text();
  richiamo_id = (event.target.id);
  $("#log").html("You clicked: " + testo + id);
  if (testo === ' ') {
    $("#modale").modal('show');
  }
});

$("#confirm-button").click(function() {
  var selected = $("select#selezione option:selected").text();
  $("#" + richiamo_id).html(selected);
  $("#modale").modal('hide');
});
```